# Como gerar vários PDF dinamicamente através do Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estou criando um método em c# na qual o usuário entra com uma listagem de dados e aplicação monta um documento pdf para cada dado informado.

Estou utilizando a biblioteca iTextSharp. No primeiro dado ele gera o PDF conforme esperado, porém ao verificar no código ele para no `Response.End()` e impede que leia os outros dados para gerar os próximos PDFs.

A dúvida seria, como que poderia fazer para gerar os PDFs ininterruptamente até que todas as entradas do usuário tenham sido atendidas?

Código:

```
protected void btn_pdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){          
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 40f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(table);

    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Clear();

    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.OutputStream.Close();

    Response.End(); // Nesse ponto ele para o loop
}
```

Comment: De que loop você está falando??

Comment: Desculpe, acho que não ficou bem clara a minha pergunta, então, o usuário ele entra com um bloco de matrículas através de um arquivo txt, eu pego cada matrícula e consulto umas tabelas no banco, a partir dali monto o documento pdf. Porém, ele sempre para no "Response.End();" e não volta para consultar as linhas posteriores com as matrículas, ele já faz o download direto do documento.

Comment: Onde está o `Loop`?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei onde está o `loop` ai... mas você poderia fazer assim:

```
protected void btn_pdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    do{      
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 40f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(table);

        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Clear();

        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();

        Response.End(); // Nesse ponto ele para o loop
    }
    while(textBox.TextLength>0 && textBox2.TextLength>0)
}
```

caso seja o que eu entendi assim vai fazer enquanto os campos não estiverem todos preenchidos

**PS**: é só uma sugestão, já que a pergunta não está clara...

Comment: No caso, os campos sempre estarão preenchidos, o problema seria após a geração do primeiro documento de pdf ele para no "Response.end();" e não volta para a linha posterior do TXT para fazer uma nova consulta e montar o próximo documento para o download..

Comment: para explicar melhor, o usuário entra com um bloco de matrículas através de um arquivo txt, eu pego cada matrícula e consulto umas tabelas no banco, a partir dali monto o documento pdf. Porém, ele sempre para no "Response.End();" e não volta para consultar as linhas posteriores com as matrículas, ele já faz o download direto do documento.